# why mysql query treat string in where condition for bigint field as 0 (zero)?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE `Test`( `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, `S_ID` BIGINT(20), PRIMARY 
KEY (`Id`) );

ID | S_ID
...|....
1  | 0
2  |121
```

And when I run MYSQL query

```
Select * from test where S_ID = 'Any_charecter'
```

return result set

```
ID | S_ID
...|....
1  | 0
```

Please tell why this is so?How can I overcome this using MYSQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the string is implicitly converted to a number. When the string begins with a number, this number is used. Else it gets converted to 0.

Solution 1: When you store numbers, don't compare them to strings. Simple as that.

Solution 2: Change the datatype of S_ID to varchar or char. But then again, why would you store a number in a string? In your database design you should try to avoid mixing several datatypes in one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @s = 'Any_charecter';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE @s REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND  S_ID = @s;

SET @s = 121; -- 'Any_charecter';
SELECT * FROM test WHERE @s REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND  S_ID = @s;
```